# Tag review: [tag:mqtt], [tag:mqtt-topic], [tag:mqtt-subscription]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I wonder if [mqtt-topic](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-topic) and [mqtt-subscription](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-subscription) really add value over the more generic [mqtt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt)?

These [three questions](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-topic) currently using [mqtt-topic](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-topic) as well as those [three questions](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-subscription) using [mqtt-subscription](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-subscription) (there's an overlap) double with [mqtt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt) in either case (which is pretty obvious). I am not sure if those two specialized help categorize the questions much better though...

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

When we consider that MQTT is *an ISO standard publish-subscribe-based "lightweight" messaging protocol* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT)) where you can't subscribe without a topic and a topic doesn't make much sense without any subscribers I'd say we should make them both synonyms of [mqtt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt).

The one question that hasn't the topic tag has the word *topic* in the body and the question without the subscription tag has the word *subscribe* in the title. I see no added value by splitting these two from the hypernym tag.

Comment: Technically a topic can exist without a subscriber but as you say there is little use to it.

Comment: Agree with this; until there is a need to differentiate the different questions, just stick them all under [mqtt].

Answer (score 3):

<s>I have proposed [mqtt-topic](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-topic) and [mqtt-subscription](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-subscription) as [synonyms](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tags/mqtt/synonyms) of [mqtt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt). If you have sufficient rep and score in the [mqtt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt) tag, please vote on them if you wish for them to be synonymised. Four votes are currently required to synonymise these tags (or two downvotes to withdraw the proposal).</s>

---

Helmar has now burninated the specific tags, making synonymisation unnecessary now. If the need comes up for these tags in future, they can easily be added again.

Comment: You know that this [*skill*](http://iot.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) has limited access as of now.

Comment: @Ghanima anyone with a tag score of more than 5 can **vote**; you only need 1250 rep to suggest synonyms.

Comment: Still we don't have enough people to vote on that. It's gotta be done by SE staff for now.

Comment: @Helmar I think we do - there are 5 users with an answer score >= 5 (you only need 4). It turns out question score isn't sufficient though.